# Error with ckrecord name

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sigabrt, ckrecord

I am getting a sigabrt thread 1 error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'recordName can not be empty'
*** First throw call stack:" and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
class SweetsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var sweets = [CKRecord]()

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
    }
    func loadData()
    {
        sweets = [CKRecord]()
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Beam", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray:nil))
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]
        publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results: [CKRecord]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let sweets = results
            {
                self.sweets = sweets
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sendSweet(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Beam", message: "Type a Beam", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Your Beam"
        }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            let textField = alert.textFields!.first!
            if textField.text != ""
            {
                let newBeam = CKRecord(recordType: "Beam")
                newBeam["content"] = textField.text
                let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
                publicData.saveRecord(newBeam, completionHandler: {(record:CKRecord?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil
                    {
                        print("Beam saved")
                    }
                })
            }
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        if sweets.count == 0
        {
            return cell
        }

        let sweet = sweets[indexPath.row]

        if let sweetContent = sweet["content"] as? String
        {
            let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormat.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
            let dateString = dateFormat.stringFromDate(sweet.creationDate!)
            cell.textLabel?.text = sweetContent
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateString
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You need to point out which line is causing the error.

Comment: is doesn't directly say. how can i find out @rmaddy

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: figured it out thanks

Comment: @Caleb, if you have found what the problem was, please post an answer to help someone with the same issue.